# geometry nodes - extrude disconnected face

Tags: geometry-nodes, extrude

I'm extruding a grid primitive and joining it with itself to create a solid object but the bottom edges don't seem to get connected. My node graph looks like this:

[image]

The normals are correct but the subdivision doesn't seem to create rounded edges on the bottom - it appears the merge by distance isn't working. I have tried different values for merge by distance but don't understand why I'm getting a hard edge on the bottom (not affected by subdivision surface):
[image]

The expected result is rounded edges on the bottom (fully connected solid mesh):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry the answer hit me in the face after I posted the question... the merge by distance was in the wrong place.

correct node tree:

[image]

correct result:

[image]